# XCTest: lines covered by unit test reported as not covered

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have unit tests for my XCode project, the test result that shows lines that are covered or not has something incorrect, in the report it's like:

```
<lineToCover lineNumber="64" covered="false"/>
```

But I do have unit test covering that line, I tried with a breakpoint while running the test case and it did hit.

Is there something I need to set? It feels to me that the build for testing has those lines skipped somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe exactly how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It can depend on the code. Please show us an example.